# Discord.js v13 Slash Command Ban Command not working

Tags: discord.js

It does not ban the person I mention.
My code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const fs = require('fs');

//Ban.js
module.exports = {
    name: "ban",
    description: "This command ban's someone",
    category: "moderation",
    example: ["!ban @member"],
    callback: async ({ message, args }) => {
      try {
          
      const member = message.mentions.members.first();
      const permission = message.member.permissions.has(Discord.Permissions.FLAGS.BAN_MEMBERS)
    
      if (!permission)
        return message.reply({ 
            contents: ":failed:1050462335556386846>  | You don't have permission to use this command"
        });
    
      if (!args[0]) return message.reply({ content: `:failed:1050462335556386846>  | Please specify someone` });
    
      if (!member) return message.reply({ content: ` | Cannot find that member...` } );
    
      if (member.id === message.author.id)
        return message.reply({ content: `:failed:1050462335556386846>  | You cannot ban yourself!` });
    
      if (message.member.roles.highest.position < member.roles.highest.position)
        return message.reply({
          content: `:failed:1050462335556386846>  | You cannot ban user who have higher role than you...`
        });
    
      if (!member.bannable) return message.reply({ content: `:failed:1050462335556386846>  | I cannot ban that member `});
    
      return (
        (await member.ban()) +
        message
          .reply({
            content: `:anger: | User ${member} has been banned`
          })
          .then((msg) => {
            setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 5000);
          })
      );
        } catch(err) {
          message.reply({ content: `:failed:1050462335556386846> There was an ${err}` })
        }
    }, };
```

Comment: Are there any errors? Have you done some basic debugging or should we just check all your code without any additional info?

Comment: This is what it gives me in the console: https://pastebin.com/K1sXrGTf

Comment: Voted to close as a typo, `callback` should be `execute`

Comment: Now I get this: 
UnhandledPromiseRejection : TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reply')

Comment: Show us your command handler

Comment: The index.js you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `command.execute(message, args)` to execute your command, you should use `command.callback({ message, args })`. This is why it does not work, your core function is not executed.